# Memory explosion with boolean indexing in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, sparse-matrix, pytables

I am working with a very large data series of floats in Pandas 12.0. What I am trying to do is set extreme outliers to NaNs in this series, which represents a standardized feature vector (mean is 0, std is 1).

I have no trouble making a boolean mask of the feature vector to find extreme outliers:

```
mask = feature_series > 10 | feature_series < 10
```

This takes minimal resources. However, when I attempt to actually use this mask I get a memory explosion and have to force exit before a crash occurs. This happens with:

```
feature_series[mask] = np.nan
```

It's not limited to this operation either. I also get a memory explosion with:

```
mask.any()
```

What's making this happen? I feel like it may be a bug, but I'm still relatively new to Pandas and can't be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you need some parentheses

```
mask = (feature_series > 10) | (feature_series < 10)
```

Comment: And missing parentheses are once again the culprit. Thank you!